# 2 phase locking with added increment mode

Tags: transaction, locking

I have this assignment question where increment mode is added in addition to read and write lock modes in two phase locking.But I cant seem to figure out whether each lock mode has its own seperate type of unlock method (like read unlock(x),write_unlock(x)),or we unlock all the locks acquired on the item with a single unlock(x) at the end.Can anyone please explain me the asnwer to the following question along with an example if possible.Thanks
[image]

That was the question and the place where I got stuck is according to the lock compatibility matrix given in the problem while a transaction is performing an increment operation on an item x (acquired an increment lock)other transactions can simultaneously acquire increment lock on the same item x and perform increment operations just like shared mode(where if a transaction holds read lock on an item x other transactions too can acquire read lock on x ) where as increment lock is conflict to read and write operations .so suppose the following non serial schedule which follows 2pl

```
T1          |           T2
```

lock-s(x)

read(x)

lock-i(x)

x = x + v

```
                      lock-s(y)

                        read(y)
```

lock-x(x)

lock-s(y)

write(x)

unlock(x)

```
                    lock-i(y)(cant acquire this lock since read lock on y is not released in transaction t1 ,hence waits)
                      y = y + v
```

read(y)

lock-i(y)(cant acquire this lock since read lock on y is not released in transaction t2 ,hence t1 also waits)

y = y + v

lock-x(y)

write(y)

unlock(y)

likewise both transactions enter into deadlock.No matter what example I try to take I get a deadlock .Can anyone please give me a schedule where the transactions dont enter into deadlock and they follow 2 Phase locking protocol